# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function after second refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I'm facing a javascript problem. This is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
        createNewTodo("_OPDRACHT_", "_PRIO_", "_DONE_");

        _OPDRACHT_  =   wat er gedaan met worden.
        _PRIO_      =   prioriteit 1-5 (1 is hoogste, 5 is laagste)
        _DONE_      =   uitgevoerd 1-2 (1 is nee, 2 is ja
    */

    function todo(opdracht,prio,done) {
      this.opdracht = opdracht;
      this.prio = prio;
      this.done = done;
    }

    function createNewTodo(opdracht,prio,done) {
      var createdTodo = new todo(opdracht,prio,done);
      if ( localStorage.todoCount == undefined ) {
          localStorage.setItem('todoCount', 0) 
      }
      var todoSize = parseInt(localStorage.todoCount) + 1;
      commitToStorage(todoSize,createdTodo);
    }

    function addList(){
        var val = $('#name').val();
        var tjap = createNewTodo(val,"1","1");
    }

    function commitToStorage(objectCount,newObject) {

      var item = + objectCount;
      localStorage.setItem('todoCount', objectCount);

      localStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify(newObject));
    }

    var todoCount = localStorage.getItem('todoCount');  
    for (i=1;i<=todoCount;i++)
      {
        var number = parseInt(i) + 1;
        var todo = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(+ i));
        createMarkup(todo);
      } 

    function createMarkup(todo) {
      $('ul#items').append(
        "<li>" + 
          todo.opdracht + " " +
        "</li>"
      );
    }

    $('#add-btn').click(addList);

});
```

When I click on the add-btn it will insert a item in localstorage with a array of values. Everything is working fine until I refresh the page. At the first time I can add as many items in localstorage without a problem but when I try to add items after refreshing the page I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function. Been searching a lot on the internet but could't find a appropriate solution for this. Anyone that can help me out and push me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no separated local scope inside `for` loop so you are assigning an object to your variable called `todo` that was previously declared as a function instead of creating a new local variable with the same name to store your todo data.

You can read more about this particular topic and most of the features and 'pitfalls' of the language on http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes . I would strongly suggest you to read the whole page, it will save you a lot of time in the future.